# Consider the autonomous ODE y’=f(y) and compute the consistency order of the explicit Euler method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

Consider the autonomous ODE $y’=f(y)$ and compute the consistency order of the explicit Euler method.
I’m not sure whether my solution is correct. Please help me to correct it if there is any problem. Thanks!
My solution to this problem is
\begin{align}
\tau(s,y,h,f)&=\frac{y(s+h)-\psi(s,y,h,f)}{h}
\\[.5em]
\psi(s,y,h,f)&=y(s)+hf(y(s))
\\[.5em]
\tau(s,y,h,f)&=\frac{y(s+h)-y(s)-hf(y(s))}{h}
\\&=\frac{y(s)+y{}’(s)h+\frac{1}{2}y{}’’(s)h^2+O(h^3)-y(s)-h{}’(s)}{h}
\\&=\frac{\frac{1}{2}y{}’’(s)h^2+O(h^3)}{h}
=\frac{1}{2}y{}’’(s)h+O(h^2)=O(h)
\end{align}

Comment: Please use the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc).

Comment: Hi I have added more information. Thank you very much!

Comment: It would be helpful if you introduce $\tau$ and $\psi$ properly.